# Converting an object to a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, rubygems

In Ruby (without Rails), is there a simple way to convert an object into a hash?  I have done some searching and similar Rails solutions had the OP try using .attributes.  Is there anything similar to this in plain Ruby?  Any Gems?

Each of these objects represents a row from a CSV file I create here:

```
game_teams_data = CSV.read(location[:game_teams], headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
    @@game_teams = game_teams_data.map do |row|
```

I am then accessing the object here in an enumerable

```
@@game_teams.each do |game|
     game
end
```

Not sure if this makes a difference for how I could do the conversion below.

My object
`#<GameTeam:0x00007ffe9c97d158 @game_id="2012030154", @team_id="30", @hoa="home", @result="LOSS">`

Output I'm trying to achieve
`hash = {game_id => "2012030154", team_id => "30", hoa => "home", result => "LOSS"}`

Comment: What objects from CSV? We need to see some CSV input, and the content of the objects being generated. See "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Comment: If you're just learning Ruby try and steer far, far away from class variables like `@@game_teams`. Instead make use of instance variables like `@game_teams` but do this inside of an object, as in an instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't update `GameTeam` to add a `to_h` method, then you can get the needed instance variables and make your own:

```
class GameTeam
  def initialize(game_id, hoa, result, team_id)
    @game_id = game_id
    @hoa = hoa
    @result = result
    @team_id = team_id
  end
end

obj = GameTeam.new('2012030154', 'home', 'LOSS', '30')
%i[game_id hoa result team_id].map { |ivar| [ivar, obj.instance_variable_get("@#{ivar}")] }.to_h
# {:game_id=>"2012030154", :hoa=>"home", :result=>"LOSS", :team_id=>"30"}
```

Comment: That's certainly one way, but making a `GameTeam#to_h` method is more conventional.

Answer (score 5):

I would add a `to_h` method to the `GameTeam` class:

```
class GameTeam
  # existing code

  def to_h
    { game_id: @game_id, team_id: @team_id, hoa: @hoa, result: @result }
  end
end
```

And would then call that method like this:

```
@@game_teams.each do |game_team|
  game_team.to_h
end
```

Comment: If the class has "getter" methods (aka attribute readers) for the instance variables use them instead of using the variable directly. If not, using the instance variables is fine.